# Rails 4 - nested forms with Cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I use simple form with Cocoon gem.

In development mode, I have all of this working correctly, however in production mode its a big mess.

I have profile model and a qualifications model.

The associations are:

**profile.rb**

```
has_many :qualifications  
accepts_nested_attributes_for :qualifications,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

**qualification.rb**

```
belongs_to :profile
```

In my profiles new form, I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@profile, multipart: true) do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>

              <div class="form-inputs">

            <div class="intpol2">
              Your professional qualifications
            </div>
            <%= f.simple_fields_for :qualifications do |f| %>

              <%= render 'qualifications/qualification_fields', f: f %>  
            <% end %>
            </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

               <%= link_to_add_association 'Add a qualification', f, :qualifications, partial: 'qualifications/qualification_fields' %>

            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="row">
```

In my qualifications fields new form, I have:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
<div class="container-fluid">



          <div class="form-inputs">


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <%= f.input :title, :label => "Your award" %> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">


                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <%= f.input :level,   collection: [ "Bachelor's degree", "Master's degree", "Ph.D", "Post Doctoral award"] %>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-6">
                <%= f.input :year_earned, :label => "When did you graduate?", collection: (Date.today.year - 50)..(Date.today.year) %>
                </div>

          </div>


          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <%= link_to_remove_association 'Remove this qualification', f %>
                </div>

          </div>


          </div>

</div>  
</div>
```

In development, when I click the link to add a new qualification, it reloads the profile new form, but does not reveal the qualifications field form.

I have the same setup with address model (same as qualification).

All of this works in development, but not in production.

Is there an extra step required to get this working in production?

My qualifications controller:

```
class QualificationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_qualification, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /qualifications
  # GET /qualifications.json
  def index
    @qualifications = Qualification.all
    authorize @qualifications
  end

  # GET /qualifications/1
  # GET /qualifications/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /qualifications/new
  def new
    @qualification = Qualification.new
    authorize @qualification
  end

  # GET /qualifications/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /qualifications
  # POST /qualifications.json
  def create
    @qualification = Qualification.new(qualification_params)
    authorize @qualification

    respond_to do |format|
      if @qualification.save
        format.html { redirect_to @qualification }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @qualification }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @qualification.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /qualifications/1
  # PATCH/PUT /qualifications/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @qualification.update(qualification_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @qualification }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @qualification }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @qualification.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /qualifications/1
  # DELETE /qualifications/1.json
  def destroy
    @qualification.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to qualifications_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_qualification
      @qualification = Qualification.find(params[:id])
      authorize @qualification
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def qualification_params
      params[:qualification].permit(:profile_id, :level, :title, :year_earned, :institution)
    end
end
```

My profiles controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  after_action :verify_authorized

  # GET /profiles
  # GET /profiles.json
  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
    authorize @profiles
  end

  # GET /profiles/1
  # GET /profiles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /profiles/new
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
    @profile.qualifications.build
    @profile.visions.build
    @profile.personalities.build
    @profile.addresses.build

    authorize @profile
  end

  # GET /profiles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /profiles
  # POST /profiles.json
  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
    authorize @profile

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @profile }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /profiles/1
  # DELETE /profiles/1.json
  def destroy
    @profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profiles_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
      authorize @profile
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def profile_params
     params.require(:profile).permit(:user_id, :title, :hero, :overview, :research_interest, :occupation, :external_profile, 
        :working_languages, :tag_list,
          user_attributes: [:avatar],
          personality_attributes: [:average_day, :fantasy_project, :preferred_style],
          vision_attributes: [:long_term, :immediate_challenge], 
          qualifications_attributes: [:id, :level, :title, :year_earned, :institution, :_destroy],
          addresses_attributes: [:id, :unit, :building, :street_number, :street, :city, :region, :zip, :country, :latitude, :longitude, :_destroy] )
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you include code from your controller?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved when I precompiled my assets